# Storing two digit user input

Tags: assembly

I am working on a program to store user input as a hexi value in AL.  If the user enters a 9 and then a 4, I want to ultimately store 94h in AL.  This part is working.  Now, if the user enters a B first and then a 4, I want to store B4h in AL.  This is where I am stuck.  I am new to assembly, so don't beat me up too much - I know its not pretty!  The issue I am having is once I have 0Bh in DH and 04h in DL, how would I concatenate them to get B4h?

Note: I am not done with the jump instructions, and I know I need to finish them up.

```
ReadHexByte proc
call ReadChar
cmp al, 39h
jbe number
cmp al, 41h
jz letter_a
cmp al, 42h
jz letter_b
cmp al, 43h
jz letter_c
cmp al, 44h
jz letter_d
cmp al, 45h
jz letter_e
cmp al, 46h
jz letter_f

number: mov dh, al
    sub dh, 30h
    shl dh, 4
    call ReadChar
    sub al, 30h
    add al, dh

letter_a: mov dh, 0Ah
     shr dh, 4
     call ReadChar
     sub al, 30h
     add al, dh
letter_b: mov dh, 0Bh
     call ReadChar
     sub al, 30h
letter_c: mov dh, 0Ch
     call ReadChar
     sub al, 30h
     add al, dh
letter_d: mov dh, 0Dh
     call ReadChar
     sub al, 30h
     add al, dh
letter_e: mov dh, 0Eh
     call ReadChar
     sub al, 30h
     add al, dh
letter_f: mov dh, 0Fh
     call ReadChar
     sub al, 30h
     add al, dh

ReadHexByte endp
```

Comment: both `dh` and `dl` are 8 bit registers. And single hexadecimal digit is covering exactly 4 bits (0000 = 0, 0001 = 1, ..., 1111 = F). So when you have `0Bh` in `dh`, you have it 4 bits too low. By shifting that value 4 bits up (`shl` instruction) you will prepare it for merge, i.e. `0Bh<<4 = 0B0h`. Then you can merge them with `or` or `add` (in case you are sure the `dl` has clear upper 4 bits and `dh` has clear lower 4 bits, the both `or` and `add` will yield the same binary result, they would mix the bits differently would there be some overlap of set bits.

Comment: and your procedure doesn't finish with `ret`, so the CPU will mindlessly continue with the next value in memory after that `add al,dh` interpreting it as x86 instruction (whatever value will be following in memory that code, even if it's "data", doesn't matter, byte is byte and next instruction is next instruction).

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks for the explanation.  I changed shr to shl and its working.  Also added return instructions.

Answer (score 1):

In your code with jump per FIRST-INPUT letter you can actually hardcode all those inits as `mov dh,0B0h` -> problem solved...

But that's extra ugly, how about **computing** some values?

Like comparing first input against `'A'`, and if it's below, skip next patch; patch-code can subtract 7 and it will turn letter A (41h) into 3Ah, etc.. up to letter F into 3Fh; and then you can process the value in the same way for both letter (patched into 3A..3F values) and digit (30..39), just shifting them 4 bits up = DH is ready.

Like this:

```
ReadHexByte proc
    ; this routine doesn't handle invalid input and
    ; only uppercase A-F letters are supported!

    ; read first hexa digit (char)
    call ReadChar
    cmp al, 39h
    jbe firstCharWasDigit
    sub al, 'A'-('0'+10)    ; convert letters "A..F" into 3A..3F value
        ; your assembler should assemble that above as "sub al, 7"
        ; if it does not support math expressions, write it with 7
firstCharWasDigit:
    mov dh, al      ; dh = 30h..3Fh depending on valid input (0..9A..F)
    shl dh, 4       ; move low 4 bits into upper 4 bits
        ; there is no need to do sub dh,30h before shift, because shift
        ; will throw away the upper 4 bits anyway

    ; read second hexa digit (char)
    call ReadChar
    sub al, '0'     ; convert ASCII into 0..9 (digits) and 17..22 (A-F)
    cmp al, 9
    jbe secondCharWasDigit
    sub al, 'A'-('0'+10)    ; sub al, 7 to fix letter values to 10..15
secondCharWasDigit:

    ; compose low 4 bits in AL with high 4 bits in DH into AL
    ; (it actually does compose 8 bits with 8 bits, but previous code
    ; does ensure that only low/high 4 bits are set for valid inputs)
    or  al, dh
    ret
ReadHexByte endp
```

The computer is like overgrown calculator, so before mindlessly writing ton of lines, try to check if there's some more generic formula for the results you want to achieve and if you can actually somewhat calculate them.